# Raspberry Pi: Uninstall piJS from Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, uninstallation, raspbian

How to uninstall piJS from a Raspberry Pi (from cmd-line or remove the files)?

I can't remove it because it's installed with curl and I can't unlink my Pi from pijs.io.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 4):

piJS is not an apt-get package. Here's the commands to stop the service, remove the file that has it start on boot, and update.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/pijs stop
sudo rm /etc/init.d/pijs
sudo update-rc.d pijs remove
```

And finally, remove the `pi-steroid` and `forever` node packages.

```
sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pi-steroid
sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever
```

I believe that's everything but I may be wrong. You can also remove `/tmp/pijs-precompiled.tar.gz` if you're impatient.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
apt-get remove piJS
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the package was not found. I also tried lowercase.